# glRotate changes coordinates so that the rectangle draws on a rotated plane

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es, matrix

I am running into an issue here. I set up a square projectile with a velocity x an y, and draw the actual square to the location, by setting the vertex positions there like so.

Code:

```
vertices.put(new float[] { x1, y1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                     x2, y2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                     x3, y3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                     x4, y4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0f, 0.0f });
                 //  x   y   r  g  b  A   u|s  v|t
```

where all the x's are locations of corners that i pass in.

I then move this rectangle (l2rArrow) along the x & y axis, and have the screen follow it:

```
    boolean hasTranslated = false;
    if (!l2rArrow.isFired) { // if the arrow has not yet been fired we render it thus
        gl.glPushMatrix(); //save our state

            gl.glTranslatef(l2rArrow.GetToOriginX, l2rArrow.GetToOriginY, 0f); // translate to origin 0,0,0
            gl.glRotatef(LBow.getAngle(), 0f, 0f, 1f); //rotate
            gl.glTranslatef(-l2rArrow.GetToOriginX, -l2rArrow.GetToOriginY, 0f); // translate to where we want to draw it

            texture.bind(gl, Texture.TEXTURE_L2RARROW);
            mRect = new MeshRect(l2rArrow.getMyRect());
            mRect.Draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, gl);


        gl.glPopMatrix(); //return to saved state

    } else { // the arrow has been fired so we need to render it like this and have the "camera" follow it

        hasTranslated = true;
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
            float camX = (float) ((l2rArrow.startX - l2rArrow.PosX));
            float camY = (float) ((l2rArrow.startY - l2rArrow.PosY));
            if (camY > 0) { camY = 0;}
            if (camX < -4800) { camX = -4800;}

            gl.glTranslatef(camX, camY,0f);



                l2rArrow.Update(deltaTime);
                texture.bind(gl, Texture.TEXTURE_L2RARROW);
                mRect = new MeshRect(l2rArrow.getMyRect());
                mRect.Draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, gl);

        if (l2rArrow.hasCollided) {
            //run collision code for detecting a hit and ending turn
        }
    }
```

this works as well. When the projectile is fired we will follow it perfectly. Now though I want the arrow head to point at the angle the arrow is traveling. So I need to rotate the arrow to in mid flight. I tried translating this arrow back to 0,0 rotating it, and the putting it back but when i put the arrow back it draws on the coordinates of a rotated plane.

```
    } else {

        hasTranslated = true;
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
            float camX = (float) ((l2rArrow.startX - l2rArrow.PosX));
            float camY = (float) ((l2rArrow.startY - l2rArrow.PosY));
            if (camY > 0) { camY = 0;}
            if (camX < -4800) { camX = -4800;}

            gl.glTranslatef(camX, camY,0f);

            gl.glPushMatrix();  

                gl.glTranslatef(l2rArrow.GetToOriginX, l2rArrow.GetToOriginY, 0f); // translate to origin 0,0,0
                gl.glRotatef((float) l2rArrow.getAngle(), 0f, 0f, 1f); //rotate
                gl.glTranslatef(-l2rArrow.GetToOriginX, -l2rArrow.GetToOriginY, 0f);

                l2rArrow.Update(deltaTime);
                texture.bind(gl, Texture.TEXTURE_L2RARROW);
                mRect = new MeshRect(l2rArrow.getMyRect());
                mRect.Draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, gl);

            gl.glPopMatrix();

        if (l2rArrow.hasCollided) {
            //run collision code for detecting a hit and ending turn
        }
    }
```

I understand this. How do I rotate the arrow, and then move it back into position on a non-rotated plane?

The arrow rests when it comes to Y=0, and as of right now Y=0 runs at the angle of the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and deliberation I decided to switch the way I place objects in my world.
I now use what seems to be the Normal method which is to glTranslate them into place.

Everything now works perfectly.

Apparently the way I was doing it before was getting screwed up because drawing the vertex directly into the space you want it (not drawing it at the origin and then translating it) can get pretty messy.